# How to make a function take in an array of numbers and give the ones less than 70?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

"write a JavaScript function that is called countFailing that takes in an array of grades and returns the number of failing grades (grades below 70).

The function must take in one parameter that will contain an array of grades (for example, [100, 90, 100, 50, 80, 60])
The funciton must return how many grades are faliing, where failing is a grade below 70" That's the problem

-this is what i have so far, but when i try and submit it it says, " we called "countFailing(100,70,90)" (random numbers) andyour answer returned 2, when it should have been 0"

```
//enter code here 
var counter = 0;
var grades = "[]";
function countFailing(grades) 
{
    for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
    {
        if (grades[i] <= 69 )
        {
            counter++;
    }
    } return (counter);
}
```

Comment: ^^ and we are all very thankful for that!

Comment: if this is an assignment you should do this on your own, its for your own benefit anyway, dont take the easy way out

Comment: @Ghost I think that is exactly what the OP did :)

Comment: not exactly php related either

Comment: @jangroth the answer is almost there, just some few modifications, its just more gratifying when you do this yourself

Comment: Oops, I missed that. Agreed that _enter code here_ is not so cool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it, change it to like this

```
var grades = [100, 90, 100, 50, 80, 60];
function countFailing(gradesArr){
var counter = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < gradesArr.length; i++){
    if (gradesArr[i] < 70 )
        counter++;
} 
return counter;
}

alert(countFailing(grades));
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/d79fj965/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the [**`Array.filter()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method

```js
var grades = [100, 90, 100, 50, 80, 60];

function isLessthan(element) {
  return element >= 70;
}
var filtered = grades.filter(isLessthan);

alert(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you assign `grades` to `"[]"` and treated it as a string where in fact, it should be `[]` only.

Answer (score 0):

With all the different suggestions you're getting I though I'd throw in a way using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
function foo(grades) {
    return grades.reduce(function (sum, now) {return now < 70 ? sum + 1 : sum;}, 0);
}

foo([50, 60, 70, 80]); // 2
```